# Is it possible to hide a UIToolbar with an animation?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitoolbar

I know this code is available to `UINavigationController` only.

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 9):

An example using blocks. This will hide a toolbar at the top of an iPad screen.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.7 
                 animations:^(void)
                 {
                     CGRect toolbarFrame = self.toolbar.frame;
                     toolbarFrame.origin.y = -44; // moves iPad Toolbar off screen
                     self.toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                 {
                     self.toolbar.hidden = YES;
                 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"hideView" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:toolBar cache:YES];
toolbarFrame.origin.y = 380;
toolBar.frame = toolbarFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

you can modify the toolBar 'y' origin.